# How do I align text in the same line?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this text to be in the same line but I'm not getting the hang off it

```css
#logo {
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  font-family : 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-weight : 300;
  text-align  : center;
  width       : 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="logo">This text
  <p>should be inline</p>
</h1>
```

Comment: The site is not brutal, just the users need to ask meaningful questions. In your case you use two block tags `h1` and `p`. If you would like the text to be on one line, replace `p` with a `span`.

Comment: @Azu props to you for being the fastest commenter alive xD

Comment: @FlorianBecker It work's !! I love the concept off this website just the banned system is kind of broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About that, use a `span` instead of a paragraph.

By default, paragraphs have `display: block`, so they will be in a new line, you can modify that part but a paragraph inside a title doesn't make sense

We use `span` for this kind of scenario, not sure why you need to wrap the `should be inline` inside a new element but `span` is the element you need for most font styling use cases

Comment: Works like a charm thanks for taking your time to help me with this !

Answer (score 1):

can you try this :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1 id="logo">This text<span>should be inline</span></h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of answers stating the `<p>` tag should be replaced with a `<span>` and that is correct in most cases.

## HOWEVER:

if you want to keep your setup with a `<p>` (which you probably shouldn't cause it makes no sense from another programmers-view), you can also giv the `<p>` tag a style. Use `display: inline` for forcing the `<p>` tag to behave like a `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is short for "paragraph" and thus creates a new paragraph. If you want both to be in the same paragraph, replace `<p>` with `<span>` like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="logo">
      This text
      <span>should be inline</span>
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could also change the default stylesheet for `<p>` probably so that it behaves like `<span>` but that would be more complicated imo.